# keyword "cpu" of C++

Tags: c++, keyword

What does the keyword "cpu" mean in C++?
I found this keyword with the following steps

1. I tried to write `cout`, but I mistakenly wrote `cpu`.
2. I saw that "cpu" was colored to blue - the color that show "keywords".
3. So I tried to search about keyword "cpu" mean, but I couldn't find about that.

That is why I ask this at here. Please, answer kindly :D

p.s. I am Korean, so if you find a grammatical error, tell me about that error, please. I will not be angry, I'll be very happy!! :D

Comment: `cpu` is not a keyword in standard C++. Your compiler might give it a special meaning.

Comment: In addition to what @PeteBecker said above, C++ compilers generally aren't responsible for syntax highlighting -- it may just be a bug in your IDE's syntax highlighter.